# What is the purpose of n_splits in sklean.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have recently started working with sklearn and stumble on the Stratified

ShuffleSplit function. Even though I understand its concept and what it is meant to do I don't quite understand the arguments it needs to have to function such as *n_split*. Based on the documentation of sklearn it is written that

> n_splits : int, default 10 Number of re-shuffling & splitting
>   iterations.

My best guess is that it tells the *StratifieShufflesplit* function the number of starta there are in the data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`n_splits` is a parameter of almost every cross validator. In general, it determines how many different validation (and training) sets you will create.
If you use `StratifiedShuffleSplit` it **does not** denote the number of strata - those are implied from the underlying relative frequencies of classification targets in your dataset.

See below a quote from the official docs (full link [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#cross-validation-iterators-for-i-i-d-data))

> **StratifiedShuffleSplit**
>
> StratifiedShuffleSplit is a variation of ShuffleSplit, which returns
>   stratified splits, i.e which creates splits by preserving the same
>   percentage for each target class as in the complete set.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, so n_splits just is the number of test and training sets I want ( I would assume that if the dataset is small it is prefered to set it at 1). Concerning the strata, do I have to manually create them or it is all automatically done by `StratifiedShuffleSplit`.

Comment: Its done automatically based on your target vector y

Comment: What if the target vector y is entirely made out of "yes" and "no" is there any sense in using `StratifiedShuffleSplit`. Also doesn't `StratifiedShuffleSplit` look at the feature vector X? Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: It makes sense, if the ratio is 90% to 10% then this cross validator will guarantee that in your train and valid sets the distribution will be similar

Comment: Oh ok, but does `StratifiedShuffleSplit` look at X or it only takes into account the target vector y

Comment: It doesnt look at X at all (or rather it only cares about the .shape[0]), see the following link:  http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit.html#sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit.split

Answer (score 1):

For StratifiedShuffleSplit, 'n_split' specifies the number of times the data needs to be sampled from each strata in the proportion mentioned in 'test_size'.

Example: Here's an example of a dataset containing 4 strata and each strata containing 3 records each. n_split=3 and test_size=0.3 gives:

Test data has one record from each strata and overall has about 30% records of the dataset, that is, 4 out of 12.

```
---Example dataset---
df
​
ProductName Quantities
0   Mobile  20
1   Mobile  15
2   Mobile  12
3   PC  10
4   PC  8
5   PC  9
6   Tablet  5
7   Tablet  3
8   Tablet  4
9   RasPi   2
10  RasPi   1
11  RasPi   3


from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit
split = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=3,test_size=0.3,random_state=42)

for train_index,test_index in split.split(df,df['ProductName']):
    split_train = df.loc[train_index]
    split_test = df.loc[test_index]
    print("train:")
    print(split_train)
    print("test:")
    print(split_test)

---split_1---
train:
   ProductName  Quantities
5           PC           9
8       Tablet           4
0       Mobile          20
9        RasPi           2
10       RasPi           1
4           PC           8
1       Mobile          15
7       Tablet           3
test:
   ProductName  Quantities
2       Mobile          12
3           PC          10
11       RasPi           3
6       Tablet           5
---split_2---
train:
   ProductName  Quantities
7       Tablet           3
3           PC          10
2       Mobile          12
8       Tablet           4
9        RasPi           2
11       RasPi           3
1       Mobile          15
5           PC           9
test:
   ProductName  Quantities
4           PC           8
0       Mobile          20
6       Tablet           5
10       RasPi           1
---split_3---
train:
   ProductName  Quantities
2       Mobile          12
9        RasPi           2
11       RasPi           3
3           PC          10
0       Mobile          20
6       Tablet           5
8       Tablet           4
4           PC           8
test:
   ProductName  Quantities
5           PC           9
7       Tablet           3
1       Mobile          15
10       RasPi           1
```